# example extending LEON SOC with custom peripheral, AMBA AHB slave

Tags: vhdl, fpga, system-on-chip, amba

Has anyone here extended LEON3 softcore with custom hw? I'm looking for basic example how to add custom peripheral to AMBA AHB bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this document can help ?

http://people.xiph.org/~j/bzr/theora-fpga/doc/leon3_integration/

JC